# Base and offset in register

Tags: mips, mips32

First of all, what is the difference between something like 4($s3) and $s3 ? From what I understand, 4($s3) is a memory address and $s3 is a register. Am I correct?

Next up, what is the source register in the following two cases:

1. lw, $t0, 4($s3)
2. lw, $t1, 12($s3)

In my opinion, the source registers in both these cases would be simply "$s3". I have been told that this is incorrect and the correct answers would be 4($s3) and 12($s3) respectively? Which of  these answers is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between 4($s3) and $s3 is that the former uses indirection (i.e. use the value in $s3 to compute the address from which you want to retrieve the information from). In the example you stated, 4($s3) would refer to the address equal to the value in (register $s3) + 4. The $s3 would refer to just register $s3 itself.

To be precise, typically it is called 'source operand/address' rather than 'source register', because it may not be a register. In this case it is 4($s3) and 12($s3) because that is where the data to be interacted with is stored. We are using indirection from the value in $s3 to locate what address to retrieve the data from(the actual source).

Comment: Just a follow up on that. So, 4($s3) has no correlation to $s3 whatsoever, except that it provides the value of the base address ($s3) to be added 4 bytes to? 

If true, this means that value in 4($s3) is not even saved in register $s3? If true, where is it saved?

Comment: Yup there's no correlation whatsoever. It is computed then immediately used and isn't persisted.

Comment: To clarify, the question of where the 'intermediate value' could be temporarily stored is partially answered by this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/291850/212416